# File API - HTML5 App to store videos

Tags: javascript, html, video, local-storage

I'd like to know if HTML5 API may fit this use case:

- some videos are present on a public server (say http://videosanbox.me/video.mpg)
- the JS/html5 app should store the videos locally in order to be able to play them also off-line (videos are public, there are no security
  warnings)

In my initial tests I am unable to go past the  "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" error.

In my understanding the following script should:

- request with a get the content located at the given URL
- prepare 1Mb file somewhere (I assume I'll have other errors here, but I'll get there when I'll see them:))

for now I'm interested in understanding why this error is happening, wouldn't it be normal for a client (a mobile browser) to query for resources which are not already on it?

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://videosanbox.me/video.mpg', true);

xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {

  window.requestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('video.mpg', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {

        writer.onwrite = function(e) { alert('writing'); };
        writer.onerror = function(e) { alert('error'); };

        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'video/mpg'});

       writer.write(blob);

      }, onError);
    }, onError);
  }, onError);
};

xhr.send();
```

onError is just doing something in case of error: function onError(e) {console.log('Error', e);}

Comment: Is this hosted on the same server? Is this web page also at videosanbox.me?

Comment: No, the webpage will be wrapped inside a mobile app thanks to PhoneGap, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

On the server side, you need this header to be passed:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Unfortunately, that may not be possible if you don't have control over videosanbox.me. If not, contact them and see if they're willing to allow this. If not, don't worry, there's a second solution:

**Solution 2**

Create a web page on your own server and allow cross site scripting (but use security to restrict who can use this page). In that page's code, it will take the request and open an HTTP connection to  http://videosanbox.me, retrieve the mpg file and spit it back to the PhoneGap app as a Blob. Your PhoneGap would connect to *this* page (on your server) via Ajax instead of  http://videosanbox.me.